# viewing javascript console.log or opening camera on ios simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, microblink

I implemented blinkid-react-native in react native ios app. blinkid-react-native will give me the ability to scan id's and veirfy the data on them. When i run my code i get json with only the address showing.

Since I can't open the camera to scan an id from the ios simulator. i deployed the app to test flight. i need to debug and see the javascript console.logs. I'm unable to do that from test flight?

I'm not sure about how to debug the issue? Since i can't open the camera on the ios simulator to run BlinkId and go thrugh console.logs.

here is the json the i get

[image]

here is BlinkId code

```
export const scanId = async () => {
  console.log('BlinkId*****************');
  const licenseKey = Platform.select({
    ios:
      '**********',
    android:
      '**********',
  });

  BlinkIDReactNative.SuccessFrameGrabberRecognizer(mrtdRecognizer);

  var blinkIdCombinedRecognizer = new BlinkIDReactNative.BlinkIdCombinedRecognizer();
  blinkIdCombinedRecognizer.returnFullDocumentImage = true;
  blinkIdCombinedRecognizer.returnFaceImage = true;

  const scanningResults = await BlinkIDReactNative.BlinkID.scanWithCamera(
    new BlinkIDReactNative.BlinkIdOverlaySettings(),
    new BlinkIDReactNative.RecognizerCollection([
      blinkIdCombinedRecognizer /*, mrtdSuccessFrameGrabber*/,
    ]),
    licenseKey,
  )
    .then((result) => handleResult(result))
    .catch((e) => e);
  return scanningResults;
};
console.log('BlinkId+scanningResults*****************');
console.log(this.scanningResults);
console.log('BlinkId+result1*****************');
console.log(this.result);
const handleResult = (result) => {
  function buildResult(result, key) {
    if (result && result != -1) {
      return key + ': ' + result + '\n';
    }
    return '';
  }
  console.log('BlinkId+result2*****************');
  console.log(result);
  function buildDateResult(result, key) {
    if (result) {
      return (
        key +
        ': ' +
        result.day +
        '.' +
        result.month +
        '.' +
        result.year +
        '.' +
        '\n'
      );
    }
    return '';
  }

  var localState = {
    showFrontImageDocument: false,
    resultFrontImageDocument: '',
    showBackImageDocument: false,
    resultBackImageDocument: '',
    resultImageFace: '',
    results: '',
    showSuccessFrame: false,
    successFrame: '',
  };
  console.log('BlinkId+result3*****************');
  console.log(result);
  if (result instanceof BlinkIDReactNative.BlinkIdCombinedRecognizerResult) {
    let blinkIdResult = result;
    console.log('BlinkId+blinkIdResult*****************');
    console.log(blinkIdResult);
    let resultString =
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.firstName, 'First name') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.lastName, 'Last name') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.fullName, 'Full name') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.localizedName, 'Localized name') +
      buildResult(
        blinkIdResult.additionalNameInformation,
        'Additional name info',
      ) +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.address, 'Address') +
      buildResult(
        blinkIdResult.additionalAddressInformation,
        'Additional address info',
      ) +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.documentNumber, 'Document number') +
      buildResult(
        blinkIdResult.documentAdditionalNumber,
        'Additional document number',
      ) +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.sex, 'Sex') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.issuingAuthority, 'Issuing authority') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.nationality, 'Nationality') +
      buildDateResult(blinkIdResult.dateOfBirth, 'Date of birth') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.age, 'Age') +
      buildDateResult(blinkIdResult.dateOfIssue, 'Date of issue') +
      buildDateResult(blinkIdResult.dateOfExpiry, 'Date of expiry') +
      buildResult(
        blinkIdResult.dateOfExpiryPermanent,
        'Date of expiry permanent',
      ) +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.expired, 'Expired') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.maritalStatus, 'Martial status') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.personalIdNumber, 'Personal id number') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.profession, 'Profession') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.race, 'Race') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.religion, 'Religion') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.residentialStatus, 'Residential status') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.processingStatus, 'Processing status') +
      buildResult(blinkIdResult.recognitionMode, 'Recognition mode');
    let licenceInfo = blinkIdResult.driverLicenseDetailedInfo;
    if (licenceInfo) {
      resultString +=
        buildResult(licenceInfo.restrictions, 'Restrictions') +
        buildResult(licenceInfo.endorsements, 'Endorsements') +
        buildResult(licenceInfo.vehicleClass, 'Vehicle class') +
        buildResult(licenceInfo.conditions, 'Conditions');
    }

    // there are other fields to extract
    localState.results += resultString;

    // Document image is returned as Base64 encoded JPEG
    if (blinkIdResult.fullDocumentFrontImage) {
      localState.showFrontImageDocument = true;
      localState.resultFrontImageDocument =
        'data:image/jpg;base64,' + blinkIdResult.fullDocumentFrontImage;
    }
    if (blinkIdResult.fullDocumentBackImage) {
      localState.showBackImageDocument = true;
      localState.resultBackImageDocument =
        'data:image/jpg;base64,' + blinkIdResult.fullDocumentBackImage;
    }
    // Face image is returned as Base64 encoded JPEG
    if (blinkIdResult.faceImage) {
      localState.showImageFace = true;
      localState.resultImageFace =
        'data:image/jpg;base64,' + blinkIdResult.faceImage;
    }
  } else {
    throw JSON.stringify(result);
  }
  console.log('BlinkId+localState*****************');
  console.log(localState);
  return localState;
};
```

Comment: Does this helps https://www.lifewire.com/activate-the-debug-console-in-safari-445798

Comment: @ahmed no, the solution u have an article covers web apps not native apps

Comment: What kind of environment you have? Is it a react native or ionic kind of app? Could you please throw some light on environment ?

Comment: @ahmed. the app is react native ios app. Im working in the dev env using  ios simulator. Since i can't open the camera i deployed the app to testflight.

Comment: Then you need to configure this debugger bro !!. It is quite a step but you would be able to see all components rendered, console logs and even redux state tree. https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Comment: @AmerBearat which documents are you trying to scan?
Also, are they real samples, or samples found on the internet?

Comment: @MilanParađina im scanning Arizona Driver License, Yes, It's my real licenses. I'm using blinkid-react-native V 5.9.0

Comment: To clarify, if you are not using a physical device, how are you extracting the information from the document?

Comment: @MilanParađina I'm using Physical devise, I uploaded the app on testflight, so only available to testers as beta version

Comment: @AmerBearat I understand, thank you for the clarification. Did you maybe try scanning other licenses and seeing if the behaviour is the same? Also, can you confirm that the behavior is the same with the Vision application as well? You can download it here: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microblink-vision/id1464662310

Comment: @MilanParađina I tried using My American passport and the same json came back as the image above (Without the address) but when i try using your app, it works fine for my AZ driver license .